# PIXI Event System background click

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I've migrated a project to PIXI v7.1.2 and partly this involved removing the use of `PIXI.InteractionManager` and replacing it with a `PIXI.EventSystem`. Previously I had been using interaction manager events to handle background click events, and I don't know how to replace this in PIXI's new Event System.

I've considered options of either having adding the listeners directly added to the `<canvas>` element, by I'd like to use PIXI's events such as 'pointer' events. There's also the option of adding event listeners to a root container/sprite, but I don't really like this, and also can't get it working with a transparent sprite.